# How do I debug A block ajax issue on a custom theme?

Tags: views, ajax, 9

I'm receiving and ERROR " An error occurred while attempting to process /views/ajax?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax: ajax.$form.ajaxSubmit is not a function" when clicking on link in views block on exposed form using the taxonomy terms and better exposed filters. [image]

I have tried already attach the views.ajax library to the exposed filter form. it not sorted the issue. Js aggregation also turned off.

I'm using Bootstrap Bario theme as a base and switching to it gives me same error. Core themes works fine.

How do i debug this issue or even possible solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the issue:

In custom theme I have library which had dependency of jQuery which wasn't core library (that how i got html js css template from the themeforest) I have deleted it and as a dependancy set the core/jQuery in my theme.libraries.yml file. this is solved my issue. This might be helpful to anyone experiencing such an issue and as a step to debug same issue just check that libraries are dependant on core/jquery library